# Unable to upload media files on production Umbraco server

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

So on local I'm able to upload images fine, but on my deployed website I'm unable to upload images to the media content. I receive an "internal 500 error" with the following path in chrome:

POST http://[url]/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Media/PostAddFile?origin=blueimp 500 (Internal)

I looked at umbraco logs and saw this: 2015-12-19 00:15:15,234 [P16524/D8/T73] ERROR Umbraco.Web.WebApi.Filters.FileUploadCleanupFilterAttribute - Could not acquire actionExecutedContext.Response.Content System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Umbraco.Web.WebApi.Filters.FileUploadCleanupFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)

And on the database table dbo.UmbracoLog when I try to upload it creates a new record: id userId NodeId Datestamp logHeader logComment 1885 0 0 2015-12-19 00:15:15.233 New Media 'IMG_3242.jpg' was created

These failed uploads are the only ones with a NodeId of 0. Not sure if that's strange. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using Umbraco v7.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did some digging around on this error and found that it may be a very "un" user-friendly error message. The error is coming up as null reference issue, but the real problem is the ASP.net "default" request size stopping uploading of a large image file. Added the following to the web.config and that resolved the issue:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" executionTimeout="99999"/>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Azure try removing `fcnMode="Single"` from the httpRuntime node and adding `targetFramework="4.5"`